# How to predict more than one class with random forest in python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

How can I predict more than one class with random forest in python?

I am familiar with the get probability, but how can I know to which class each probability belongs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.predict) `predict` returns an array of predicted classes you can use to get the most likely class for each sample.

If you want to use `predict_proba` to get the probability for all classes, you need to look at the `classes_` attribute. This lists the classes in the same order that `predict_proba` returned its probabilities.

Comment: How to you make it to return more than one class?

Comment: Is there a way to make in return more than one value. For my problem i can parse the classes_, but that is slow.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. Why do you expect parsing `classes_` to be slow?

Comment: If i want to find the n most likely classes. i need to find the n largest values in the get_proba matrix, which involves sorting.

Comment: Sure. But you (probably) do not have that many classes. And someone has to do the sorting, even if there was a function provided that does it for you. I would recommend, you use the simple method first to determine if the sorting is actually your bottleneck before you start optimising.